# Adding a translation phrase to Wordpress Theme

Tags: translation

I'm creating a custom Wordpress theme and I'm using exactly 3 phrases that I need to be translated according to the site language selected. I've digged a little bit through the Internet, but couldn't find an easy solution to add those phrases, so I could translate them through admin panel on my site.

I'm wondering if there is any way to add those phrases (f.e. in `functions.php` file) without using any PO/MO/POT files?

Comment: The general idea between having a theme textdomain and a language folder is that people can add `.mo` files in their own language and edit the translation without touching your `.php` theme files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea or two that you can pursue here: (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

### OPTION 1

In your template file (use a child theme if this is not your own theme), use [`get_locale`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale) in a conditional statement to check which language is set in `WPLANG` and then dish up the text according to the locale

### OPTION 2

Create yourself a function (which will be the ideal solution and what you are actually asking) using the [`gettext`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) or [`gettext_with_context`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext_with_context) filter depending on your string context.

In conjuction with `get_locale()` you can then get and transalte and serve the correct translated string according to the language set

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, finding other alternative ways to translate a theme is not recommended and will be a setback in its popularity, as **it will not allow users to add translations the same way** they do for other themes and plugins.

For alternatives, see [@PieterGoosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176901/45169)s' answer. If you asked this because you found the process of adding **i18n** to your theme overly complicated, here's a step by step, using PO/MO/POT files. (So it doesn't actually answer your specific question, but might be helpful to those who need to add theme i18n). Assuming your theme is `yourtheme`:

```
function load_yourtheme_theme_textdomain() {
    $path = get_template_directory() . '/lang';
    load_theme_textdomain( 'yourtheme',  $path);
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'load_yourtheme_theme_textdomain' );
```

You will want to wrap the translatable strings in `__()` function, using `'yourtheme'` as textdomain. For example:

```
echo __('Some text', 'yourtheme');
```

Here's a [`list of WP l18n wrappers`](http://codex.wordpress.org/L10n). Have a look a the the *related functions* on that page.

Now:

1. Download and install [Poedit](http://poedit.net/). It's free.
2. Open it, click `File`»`New`. Choose default language.
3. Save file as `.pot` in `/lang` folder, inside your theme.
4. Go to `Catalogue`»`Properties`, add in the general details of your project. Use UTF-8.
5. On `Sources Paths` (second tab), add **`../`** as base path.
6. Click the second button in the row (the one that hovers "New Item") and add a single dot **`.`** as the path of your new item. Click `Ok` to save the setting.
7. `Catalogue`»`Update from sources`.

The file will auto-grab all the translatable strings of your theme. Save again (make sure you save it as `.pot`) and you're done.

If I skipped anything or you get stuck in any step, I'll update with details.

Comment: Like your answer, but you've missed the integral part of the question unfortunately.

Comment: And PoEdit isn't really free anymore. But services like `POEditor.com` are.

Comment: @PieterGoosen See my comment under his question. I've added it before adding the answer. Than thought a walk-through with the steps would be useful on this question and added.

Comment: @kaiser It's not? I see a big green "Free Download" on their page. What am I missing?

Comment: You can't generate `.pot` files with the free version.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instruction, but it's not what I've been looking for. But anyways - thanks! It'll be definietelly useful in future projects